# TFS 2012 Admin Console Project Collections can not be deleted

Tags: tfs

When I create a project collection from in TFS Administration Console, it gets no response from there after a long time(about 10~15minutes), then I close its creating window and delete the corresponding database.
**Question**: after having done above, reopen TFS Administration Console and the collection is still exists with state "Offline(Creating...)", how to get it out from this box?
thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess that the Agent Job is either not running or is having trouble. Deletes are done in the background. Grab the BPA from the [Power Toys](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) and see if it reports any problems.

Comment: @DaveShaw **Pretty awesome** answer, thanks for your words.